# Inline check of array presence before iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually check if a collection exists before iterating over it:

```
var a1 = [1,2,3], a2;

if(a1){
    $.each(a1, function(k, v){
        console.log(v);
    });
}
```

I thought a bit about an inline solution and came up with this:

```
!a1 || $.each(a1, function(k, v){
    console.log(v);
});
```

Which seems to work fine. Any downsides or alternatives?

Without the check I would get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` exception.

http://jsfiddle.net/w1tuhtde/

Comment: Why would the collection be undefined, and not an empty array?

Comment: @elclanrs Because my back end framework doesn't serialize empty arrays.

Comment: I'd rather have empty array, so `a1 = a1 || []` then do the iteration. But first solution is readable and maintainable, second solution is just not worth it. In any case you'd do `a1 && $.each`

Comment: @elclanrs Yeah, your first suggestion is probably the best intermediate solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use the `||` operator in another way like this:

```
$.each(a2 || {}, function(k, v){
  console.log(v);
});
```

or

```
$.each(a2 || [], function(k, v){
  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: Can you please walk me through as to how jQuery evaluates such an assignment `a2 || {}`?

Comment: @Mysteryos if `a2` is defined, the whole expression evaluates to a defined object and stops without checking further the `{}`, then that object is passed in the `$.each` and it runs normally. Otherwise when `a2` is not defined, the whole expression's value depends on the remaining part which is `{}`, that part is of course defined and it stops returning that empty object. With that empty object passed in `$.each`, there is in fact no internal loop at all.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks :). In terms of performance, will @Johan code: `!a1 || $.each(a1, function(k, v){
    console.log(v);
});` run faster than yours, given that he is doing the empty object check before the call to `$.each`?

Comment: @Mysteryos yes, it is certainly faster but the difference is very very little. This is however shorter and looks better, I think.